Neovim: How to merge overloads of a function in autocompletion?
Could someone please teach me how to modify my plugin config related to autocompletion?
I'm using LazyVim with no modification to its LSP/nvim-cmp config.
By default, I find the config displaying overloads of a function as separate items, as shown in the screenshot below:

As you can see, I'm trying to call the std::max function from the <algorithm> header. Multiples overloads of this function are shown as multiple items. What's more, it's not even the first item of autocompletion suggestions.
My goal is something like this (screenshot from AstroNvim):

Overloads of std::max function are merged into one single option here. The sorting is also nice, putting std::max at the first option.
How should I modify my Neovim config to make it behave like the second image?
